# Is there a high-pass filter for videos in Adobe Premiere Pro?

Tags: premiere, adobe, filter

What I want to do is putting in high-pass filter effect on each image constituting a video by using Adobe Premiere Pro 13.1.2.

Premiere Pro has a high-pass filter for audios but it does not have a high-pass filter for videos as far as I can see.
Photoshop does.

I also have AfterEffects; the way to use it is welcome as well.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The high pass plugin in Photoshop doesn't exist natively in After Effects or Premiere.  The Find Edges tool approximates the kind of effect you're after, but given that it's for a scientific assessment of something, probably won't work for you:
[image: mona lisa with Find Edges applied]

You could try something like the Unsharp Mask in After Effects or Premiere, and then apply it back to the original image using a Difference mode - gives this kind of effect:

[image]

If the high pass is what you need, I would export the video as an image sequence, then [Automate a Batch in Photoshop](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/processing-batch-files.html) to apply it (probably overnight).

Answer (score 0):

What do you consider a high-pass filter for videos if I may ask?

When talking about audio, the high pass filter operates similar to a low-cut, in that it cuts away the lowest frequencies of the audio spectrum and lets the high frequencies pass.

Are you looking for curves? You can adjust the shadows and the highlights of an image (which wouldn't be called high-pass or something similar tho). You can do that using lumetri color. However, comparing to a high-pass, low-cut, low-pass or high-cut, the curves don't actually cut away the brightest or darkest areas, that way you would blow out the highs and crush the blacks, which would result in a fault, not really a stylistic choice but rather actually breaking the image.

If you tell us what you want to achieve with this filter we might be able to tell you the correct name and where to find it.

Comment: Photoshops High Pass Filter selects all edges so you can only apply sharpening to those.

Comment: The video I want to apply a high pass filter is one which is generated from a kind of scientific instrument and contains scientific data. Each frame of the video has high-frequency patterns, signals I care about, and low-frequency patterns, the noise. To extract the high-frequency patterns from each frame of the movie, I want to apply a high-pass filter in PremierePro. If it's impossible, I would convert the video into a bunch of still frames and take them to Photoshop and apply the high-pass filter in Photoshop. Then, let Premiere Pro load the images as a sequence and export as a video.